# R - Subset based on column name

Tags: r, subset

My data frame has over 120 columns (variables) and I would like to create subsets bases on column names.

For example I would like to create a subset where the column name includes the string "mood".  Is this possible?

Comment: Probably something like `df[grepl("mood", names(df))]` if your data called `df`

Comment: `df[grepl("mood", names(df), fixed = TRUE)]` does not use regular expressions, i.e. in "mood." the dot is not for an arbitrary char - probably that what the op wants? Additionally it is faster (which will not really matter here)

Answer (score 2):

I generally use

```
    SubData <- myData[,grep("whatIWant", colnames(myData))]
```

I know very well that the "," is not necessary and 
    colnames 
could be replaced by 
    names
 but it would not work with matrices and I hate to change the formalism when changing objects.

Comment: Too small to edit but `SubData <- myData[ , grep("whatIWant", colnames(myData))]`