# Remove columns using column name based on levels of factors

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with a column of factors and columns with values for each factor plus additional factors that are no longer included in the data frame. Example:

```
x <- data.frame(f= toupper(sample(letters[1:3], 5, replace=T)), 
            x.A = seq(1:5),
            x.B = seq(1:5),
            x.C = seq(1:5),
            x.D = seq(1:5),
            x.E = seq(1:5))
```

Resulting in:

```
  f x.A x.B x.C x.D x.E
1 B   1   1   1   1   1
2 B   2   2   2   2   2
3 A   3   3   3   3   3
4 C   4   4   4   4   4
5 A   5   5   5   5   5
```

Now I want to remove all columns that do not represent a current level in column f, resulting in a data frame:

```
  f x.A x.B x.C
1 B   1   1   1
2 B   2   2   2
3 A   3   3   3
4 C   4   4   4
5 A   5   5   5
```

Naming convention is consistent among levels and column names, and names always take the form somevariable.FACTORLEVEL. I would type all the names in a list to choose from, but it gets long and unwieldy. I tried using grep as follows:

```
subX <- x[x$f == 'B', grep('B', names(x))]
```

But don't quite get what I want and don't know how to extend that over all levels if it did work. I also looked at previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815508/r-subset-based-on-column-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame), but they don't go as far as I need. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `sub` to remove the prefix `x.` from the column names of 'x', check whether it is `%in%` the 'f' column to create a logical `vector` and use this to subset the columns of 'x'.  We removed the first column name (as it is 'f') and later concatenated with `TRUE` to include that column also in the subset.

```
 x[c(TRUE,sub('.*\\.', '', names(x)[-1]) %in% x$f)]
```

Or we can use `grepl` with `pattern` specified by `paste`ing the 'f' column to return a logical index as before.

```
x[c(TRUE,grepl(paste(x$f, collapse='|'), names(x)[-1]))]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to only do that over a range of columns? So if there were columns I wanted to keep no matter what and only remove from a set. So in this case x[,2:6]

Comment: @tjr  Suppose you want to say check the columns 3:5 and need columns 1:2 and 6 along with the columns returned by the comparison, try `x[c(rep(TRUE,2), sub('.*\\.', '', names(x)[3:5]) %in% x$f, TRUE)]`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have tried before asking the question. I found that works well. Also, I realized my question may be confusing using x as the dataframe and name, so future readers watch for that.

Answer (score 2):

This would also work.

```
x[c(T, (gsub("x.", "", names(x)) %in% x$f)[-1])]
```

Comment: `x[c(TRUE, (gsub("x.", "", names(x)) %in% x$f)[-1])]` would also work